# .htaccess in subdirectory to deny everything in subdirectory except index.php

Tags: .htaccess

Here's what the web hosted directory looks like:

- public_html

  - subdirectory

    - index.php
    - other stuff
    - .htaccess

Is there a way to make the .htaccess file deny everything relative to its location (i.e. everything in the subdirectory) except for the index.php file in that directory, without affecting anything located in its parent directory?

I've tried the following, but it's denying me access to /subdirectory/ as well.  If I do /subdirectory/index.php it seems to work.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1

<Files ./index.php>
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow from all
</Files>
```

The most ideal is if the solution is agnostic of the directory structure it's in -- that is in the future I could move everything to the parent directory, and it'd still work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the mentioned `.htaccess` location :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^(index|$) - [F]
```

That will only allow request to `index` at this directory and will not affect parent directory.

Comment: Can I know why you used `|$`?

Comment: @Kerkouch to work for both  directory/index & directory/